# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' when adding

Tags: python

I'm still  very new to Python and I have been learning it at school. I've found it pretty easy up to this point but I have been completely stumped by this and can't find a solution for what is a probably really simple question.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number. "))


print("If you add your number to your number in the form of an integer you get", number + number)
print("If you add your number to your number in the form of a string you get", number + str(number))
```

The goal of this code is to ask the user for a number then add that original number to an integer version of itself and again but instead of an integer, use a string.

e.g. 2+2 = 4 and 2+2 = 22

All it does is return the error 
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" after inputting a number and the first print statement coming out correctly.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can't concatenate string types and integer types

Comment: @Delgan Too bad about the accepted answer for that question

Comment: either you add two integers or convert the first one to string to get the string concatenation.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I just edited the offending answer to put a note at the top indicating backticks are deprecated and `str()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are trying to add together a string and a int. This is not allowed which is why you are getting this error.

To fix this problem fix your second `print()` like this:

```
print("If you add your number to your number in the form of a string you get", str(number) + str(number))
```

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding =]

Answer (score 0):

`number + str(number)` won't work; the values on *both* sides of the `+` have to be the same type.  Since `number` is an int, it has to be either `number + number` or `str(number) + str(number)`. You could also do `int(number) + int(number)`, but in this case that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question.Good luck learning :).

```
number = input("Enter a number. ")

print("If you add your number to your number in the form of an integer you get", number + number)
print("If you add your number to your number in the form of a string you get", str(number) + str(number))
```